# sql server ports 445 and 1433

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the difference between sql server ports 445 and 1433 and what is each port intended for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

445 is not a SQL port, is a SMB port. It is involved in SQL Server only if you use named pipes protocol, as named pipes are over SMB and this in turn uses 445 for '[SMB over IP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204279)', aka. as SMB 'NETBIOSless' as opposed to the old NetBIOS based SMB, which uses 137-139.

1433 is the SQL Server TCP listener port when SQL Server uses directly TCP.

To configure the server to listen on specific protocols, use [SQL Server configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx). To configure the client allowed protocols, see [Configuring Client Network Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190425.aspx).

It is better to disable Net Pipes and rely solely on TCP (1433), for reasons of performance and easy of deployment/configuration.

Answer (score 1):

445 is used to communicate using named pipes over TCP (as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839269)), 1433 is used to communicate directly over TCP.

Answer (score 0):

[INF: TCP Ports Needed for Communication to SQL Server Through a Firewall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932)